# Flying saucer: rowspan and page-break-inside

Tags: java, pdf, flying-saucer

I'm using flying saucer to convert html page to PDF. There're two huge columns that are rowspanned over whole section of the table. All columns have

```
table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

style applied. So for every other column this works fine and they are correctly truncated. While rowspanned columns don't stop at the same height on each page (see screenshot)

[image]

Any suggestions how that can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround could be to not use the rowspan at all, but instead hide the borders for the cells in the third column. So:

- remove the rowspan from the cell;
- include a `<td></td>` even for the cells that should be grouped;
- add the following styles:

``

```
tr:nth-child(n+5) td:nth-child(n+3) {
    border-top: none;
}

tr:not(:last-child) td:nth-child(n+3) {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

In the first statement the `n+5` means start hiding borders from the 5st row, so only the first 4 rows will keep the border. You may think of other kind of selectors if you get more confortable with.

Note: I don't know if the above rules work for flying-saucer, they work at least in Chrome print window, which is basically a html to pdf converter. Just try it.